# SignalR and heterogeneous types of clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm absolutely new to SignalR, so please excuse my somehow dumb question.

Let's say, I have many console apps (or windows services) that run on AWS EC2 instances, 
I have a web server (IIS with MVC3 hosted) and of course I have an infinite number of web-clients...

How can I communicate between those? Let's say

1. I need to get every few seconds in the web browser some information
   from EC2 machines - (CPU load or something like that)
2. On demand
   (when user clicks a button on a web page) it should pull something
   else (let's say AvailibleDiskSpace on C: drive) of a selected machine

What should I use - Hub or PersistentConnection? Console apps will be also clients in this case or SelfHosts (what is the SelfHost anyway?)

Is there any sample code where I can learn how to build something like that? (I believe samples on Nuget and Github and VideoTutorials show you how to build one-server/many web clients solutions but not something like I need)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is likely to host the SignalR server along with your MVC app on IIS. Don't worry about self hosting since you already have IIS set up.

I think you will have an easier time using Hubs over PersistentConnections since Hubs allow for RPC.

- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

In your console apps and windows services, I would suggest using the SignalR .NET client.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs

You can push and pull data from the console apps to the SignalR server which can then in turn can act as a *proxy* to the browser clients. Of course, the SignalR server can proxy in both directions allowing any client(s) to send realtime messages or requests to any other client(s).

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs

Your .NET and JS clients can access the same Hub or different Hubs. If all the clients access the same Hub, you might want to separate them into groups so you can distinguish between the two types of clients. If you choose to use multiple Hubs, you will likely want to make use of `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>()` to communicate with clients connected to a different Hub than the one being called.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a Hub.

Here's an example of how to do it (in 0.5.3):

Server Side (the hub):

```
public class MyDashboard : Hub
{
    /* Have this method called every few seconds via a timer */
    public void SendLoad()
    {
        // Will call the "retrieveLoad" JS method on the clients
        Clients.retrieveLoad(new {
            CPU = 10.25, // Put something relevant here
            Memory = "80%" // Again, put something relevant here
        });
    }

    public double GetDiskSpace()
    {
        return 3829847; // You'd replace the number with something more relevant
    }
}
```

Client Side (the javascript):

```
var dashboard = $.connection.myDashboard;

dashboard.retrieveLoad = function(info) {
    console.log("The CPU is at: " + info.CPU);
    console.log("The Memory is at: " + info.Memory);
}

$.connection.hub.start(function() {
    // This is called once the hub has started, so we need to wire up our click event
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        dashboard.getDiskSpace(function(space) {
            console.log("The disk space is at: " + space);
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!  Feel free to stop by our JabbR room to talk to others about the framework: http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr

NOTE:  Keep in mind if you want anything to persist on your hub (private/public variables etc.) to make that data static.

Comment: no I mean where should I put the Hub? On the MVC app, right? How then apps on EC2 machines send their stuff through web-server to the web-clients?

Comment: The EC2 machines connect to the SignalR server in you MVC app as regular clients via a .NET library called SignalR.Client. You can then let clients call a hub method on the server, which in turn broadcasts to connected clients (wheter they are JS or .NET does not matter).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of questions in one... :)

First, the console apps/windows services could just be clients the same as the browsers would be to the same `Hub`. There's no reason to drop down to the `PersistentConnection` programming model at all for this.

Second, you discuss two differenct use cases:

1. If you need to push the state of something every few seconds, this is perfect as a SignalR client side method. You would simply invoke the method on the clients based on whatever notification you might be receiving from the performance counters. This logic could either be within the Hub itself or could simply be from a client of the Hub calling a method that will then be "fanned" out to all the other clients of the hub (suggest the latter).
2. For the button press/get available space on ServerA scenario, you're talking about several layers. You somehow need to get a message from the browser to the hub to ServerA to get the result you're looking for and then respond to the browser. Honestly this isn't solved purely by SignalR. ServerA would need to have a service interface of its own that the Hub could call out to to get the result and be able to respond to the browser client. You would then have the browser call the hub method, the hub method will make a request out to ServerA, wait on the result and then return the result back to the browser. There's a lot of routing work in there to do, but nothing magical and nothing specific to SignalR. This scenario could, for all intents and purposes, be done today in a  pure web service architecture.

Next, Self-Host means the hosting of the SignalR server in a host other than IIS+ASP.NET. You could, for example, spin up your SignalR service in another console app or windows service instead of hosting in IIS+ASP.NET. You can find decent documentation on self-hosting [here in the SignalR Wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host).

As for SignalR samples, honestly there's nothing that different about what you're thinking of building than a basic documentation shows you how to do. You need to [look at the .NET client hub wiki page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs) for your console apps/windows services, you need to [look at the browser client wiki page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs) for your browser app and then you need to [look at the self hosting wiki page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host) if you want to host your server outside of IIS+ASP.NET.